# Download .apk from Url and install apk

Tags: android-studio, redirect, installation, auto-update, programmatically-created

I am fetching the problem where when the user open the application and when new version is available for the application. I want to redirect to that url. The url which i am redirect is not on the Play Store. Its independent url. It goes to that url download .apk file and install it programmatically.

Comment: Installing APK programmatically is not possible on normal android devices but can be done on rooted android devices or if your app is a system app.

Comment: See my requirment when i launch my app its version is low so i want to redirect it to new version which i place on uri download that .apk file and want to install @IbrarRaza

Comment: Whats problem you are facing redirecting to apk url or installing apk?

Comment: when i download the url in my Mobile i get install 2 different application i.e. one is with older version and other with new Version @lbrar Raza

Comment: Please be specific and explain your issue in clear words.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://diamondgame99.com/DIAMOND.apk"));my this line of code download a seperate file nd install it not on the existing file.@lbrar Raza

Comment: This code can only download "DIAMOND.apk" file but cannot install it. What do you mean by "install it not on the existing file"?

Comment: Please don't post code into the comments, use [edit] link and add the info to your question.